# How do I say "baby-faced"?

Tags: english-to-german

How do I say "baby-faced" or childish/childlike facial features in reference to a woman and in wording suitable for an ID?
I don't know any German, but I need it for a larp ;)

Comment: "suitable for an ID" - could you clarify what you mean by that? An ID card? A user name? An identification procedure? ...?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "LARP" means "Live Action Role Playing", so Joanna is probably looking for something that is suitable as the name of a character.

Comment: In case someone wears a babyface to achieve something, you might say something like "sie setzte ein Kleinmädchenlächeln auf"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"mit kindlichen Gesichtszügen"* (which translates verbatim to "with childlike facial features").

**EDIT:** Sorry, I missed the reference to a LARP [(Live Action Role Playing)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_action_role-playing_game), and thought about something like an *ID card* or *passport* (which in former times contained a description, rather than a photograph, say "1,67 m, schlank, kindliches Gesicht, blaue Augen, braune Haare"). If you're looking for something that's suitable as a name, try "Püppchen" or any of Christian Geiselmann's recommendations.

Comment: But is this suitable for an ID?

Comment: not suitable for an ID and therefore that question IMHO. If it shall be pure German, just use "Babygesicht". The description "mit kindlichen Gesichtszügen" belongs more to a dictionary than one would ever say it in speech.

Comment: *Puppengesicht*, also short *Puppe*. (lit. *doll-face*)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Oops, sorry, I missed the reference to a LARP, and thought about something like an ID card or passport (which in former times contained a description, rather than a photograph, say "1,67 m, schlank, kindliches Gesicht, blaue Augen, braune Haare").

Answer (score 2):

Simply use "Babyface". I would bet the word is so common in German that it almost qualifies for naturalized.

However, if you want to give your larp character a name connoting being nice and lovely, "Babyface" perhaps is not the best choice. The word evokes somehow the picture of a gangster by that name. In that case, consider

> Schnuckel
>
> Schnuckelchen
>
> Mausi
>
> Süßer Fratz

(I immediately distance myself from the last one, because for me this sounds sexistic. But 50 years ago it may have been an accepted way of speaking about a babyfaced women. Just because people weren't aware of the implicit power claim.)

Comment: For women this is a rather harsh nickname.

Comment: "wording suitable for an ID" - wohl kaum (Spiel hin oder her).

Comment: I agree that Babyface is fine to understand in German even for non-English speakers.

Answer (score 1):

In all honesty, I only heard "babyface" before, if all else fails call them "süß" (cute).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe *Babyface* and

> Babygesicht

(as well as the forementioned *Puppengesicht*) seem too offensive. If used in real conversation, a more common German term may be:

> Kleine

Of course it is discriminatory as well, but it is more real-life discrimination.
So it depends on you: If you want to use emphasized stereotypes in your LARP (I have no real experience with that), use one of the first words, if it shall be used in conversations, I would go with *Kleine*.

More friendly:

> Süße

But that is like *Herzchen* more in direction of sweety.
A more descriptive word (but not to use for direct speech) for an adult or adolescent woman looking younger would be :

> Kindfrau

Comment: Your suggestions for adequate expressions in German to replace "Babyface" as a nick name for a woman are actually good. But neither of them seems to be a suitable name for a larp character. "Kleine" and "Süße" are just too unspecific. "Kindfrau"... hm... pejorative even? "Babygesicht could work, but again I find this strange as a name for a figure. More typical might be "Miss Babygesicht".

Comment: I see. Maybe you are right, maybe that depends on the larp. It would have helped to have the other nick names/IDs in that game... But "neither of them seems suitable" is then likely the same for the suggestions in your answer ;-) (I can say that, because I was the only one, who upvoted your answer till now :-) Moreover: Miss "Babygesicht" or similar construction seems a good idea, only then you could use "Miss Babyface" and the question was in my eyes to get a German name.